# working with multiple connection string asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating asp.net MVC Application using MVC. I have 5 users but the Database is the same but we creating the copy of that database like dum001,dum002....so on. So, Is it possible to setup five connection strings or even more in web.config? when user login, I redirect it to his database, so then he can use his DataBase.

Comment: Not sure why you'd think there's a limit to how many connection strings you can define. As far as using a separate database per user, that's completely up to you.

Comment: but how to mention the connection string to user by using database name

Comment: That's completely up to you as well, whether you store them in a config file, a database, whatever. You'll need to find the right way to map them, if you plan on having multiple single-tenant databases.

Comment: please give one example how to map the connection string in mvc

Comment: Seriously: You need to do a bit of work yourself on this. If you're going to manage multiple databases, then you should also be able to create some type of way to map a username to a database name (just imagine the username being a *key* and the database name being a *value* - you can take it from there).

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create as many connection strings as you want in your web.config.

Depending on what data access layer you are using to access the database, you could resort to multiple methods of switching connection strings based on the user.

### Option 1: Best

Instead of storing connection strings for each user, store only one connection string to a "Master" database. This Master DB would be in charge of knowing things like users, sessions, and user-specific settings, such as which database is theirs.

When a user logs in, the Master DB can be used for user lookups and to serve up the connection string to the MVC app as a session variable for that user. This connection string data would then be used by the MVC app to dynamically create the DB connection thru your data access layer (DAL).

You'd need to cache the setting to prevent a bottleneck at the Master DB level. And of course, this would all be server side. Never expose the connection string across the wire to the client-side.

This is configurable, manageable, and preferable.

### Option 2: Hard-coded Hacky

PS. This isn't good practice and will burn you.

If you only have 5 users, and will ever only have 5 users, and will ever always have the same username for each user, you could just hard-code their username as a prefix for their connection string. Like:

Given username = ryancdotnet
Given username = armardip

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ryancdotnetConnString" connectionString="server=ServerName;database=dum001;uid=username;password=pwd;"/>
    <add name="armardipConnString" connectionString="server=ServerName;database=dum002;uid=username;password=pwd;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then you will still dynamically instantiate the DAL connection string based on who is logged in.

#### Generic example

```
using System.Configuration
[...]
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
ConnectionStrings[username + "ConnString"].ConnectionString;
```

#### EntityFramework example

```
//where MyDbContext is derived from DbContext (EntityFramework)
public void InitializeDbContext(string curUsername)
{
    myDbContext = new MyDbContext(curUsername + "ConnString");
}
```

Hope this helps you along!